# How can Url.Action already know the routevalues without me setting them?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a jquery post to an MVC action. The action returns a json result with (for example) Id = 123. Code is still in early stage, but I was very surprised to find out that Url.Action("action", "controller") is building a url complete with the id I returned from Json. Is this magic? I couldn't find documentation that says it does that.

```
// how I assumed it would need to be accomplished
// redirects to "Controler/Action/123123" where data = { id = 123 }
$.post(saveUrl, json, function (data) {
    var detailsUrl = "@Url.Action("Action", "Control")" + data.id;
    window.location = detailsUrl;
});

// rewritten without adding id to the route, not sure how this works...
// redirects to "Controler/Action/123" where data = { id = 123 }
$.post(saveUrl, json, function (data) {
    var detailsUrl = "@Url.Action("Action", "Control")";
    window.location = detailsUrl;
});
```

Just for reference, here is the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Model model)
{
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { id = 123 }};
}
```

So I guess my question is, is this by design? How does it know what to use?

---

As pointed out in the answer, Url.Action has access to existing routevalues and will attempt to reuse them. To get around this I have used the slightly hacky solution below:

```
var detailsUrl = "@Url.Action("Action", "Control", new { id = ""})" + "/" + data.id;
```

This clears out the route values so that I can attach new ones in on the client side. Unfortunately, passing null or new {} as RouteValues to Url.Action does not overcome this. A nicer approach may be to create another Action helper that guarantees no routevalues will be attached. Alternativly, there is also Url.Content, but you will lose the Action/Controller wiring in the IDE doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UrlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx) (which is the type for `Url`) has access to the route data that was used to access the current action. It will try and use these values to fill in the necessary route values for you, unless you otherwise specify them.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Here I was thinking it somehow got the route value from JSON. Great username btw.

Answer (score 0):

> is this by design?

This magic happens because of **Routing** infrastructure. Some people thing that the MVC routing is only about handling incoming requests **but it is also about generating outgoing URLs**.

The html helpers like **ActionLink** and the **UrlHelper** these all integrated with the routing module and when you try to create an outgoing URL they check the routing schema that you defined in Global.asax.cs and create the URLs accordingly.

When the schema that you defined in Global.asax.cs changes the generated URLs changes accordingly and so when you create links in your application, rely on this helpers instead of directly hardcoding them in controller or views.

Comment: I find it odd that the helper is dropping in the routevalue despite my request for it to do so. Is there a helper that just creates what I ask it to (ie, Action and Controller)? I used RenderUrl previously, but that doesn't seem to be in Razor.

Comment: My bad I misunderstood reading you question first. Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve. I believe you are doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: Well, it wasn't specifically my question, so no need to apologise. What I wanted to do was saftly generate a url in js and in the past I have generated a url with RenderUrl. Its not in Razor so I tried the UrlHelper's Action method, but it includes the id from the current route values. For now, I've just gone and used a js string, but have had issues in the past with server deployments this way.

Comment: As per my understanding the routing framework don't append the "id" to the generated url in your case and I'm wondering how it's happening.