# Url.Action not working as expected

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json.net, razor-2

I'm using the same view in two action on the same controller. 
The first view relaunches the second, but in the second round, `URL.Action` automatically inserts the url parameter

this is the code:

```
 function doRedirect() {
        debugger;
        var data = { };
        data.Modules = dict;
        data.Pages = dictPage;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ReorderModules")' + '/' + model.PhaseDocumentId,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:  JSON.stringify(data) ,
            dataType: "json",
            async:
        false,
            success:

        function(msg) {
            ////debugger;
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("UpdateModelView")' + '/' + model.PhaseDocumentId;
        }
        });
    }
```

on the first step  `@Url.Action("UpdateModelView")` is right on the second step the value is the right path + Id passed on the first step, so I have an error because I concatenate two times the same id

Any ideas?

UPDATE
 this is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult UpdateModelView(Guid id)
    {
        var model = srvDispatcher.PhaseDocumentService.GetPhaseDocumentById(id.ToString());
       .....
        ViewBag.ModelNoHtml = model;
        return View("CreatePhase2", model);
    }
```

first time the client side code is :

```
function doRedirect() {
        debugger;
        var data = { };
        data.Modules = dict;
        data.Pages = dictPage;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/PhaseDocuments/ReorderModules' + '/' + model.PhaseDocumentId,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:  JSON.stringify(data) ,
            dataType: "json",
            async:
        false,
            success:

        function(msg) {
            ////debugger;
            window.location.href = '/PhaseDocuments/UpdateModelView' + '/' + model.PhaseDocumentId;
        }
        });
```

second time the client-code is :

```
function doRedirect() {
        debugger;
        var data = { };
        data.Modules = dict;
        data.Pages = dictPage;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/PhaseDocuments/ReorderModules' + '/' + model.PhaseDocumentId,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:  JSON.stringify(data) ,
            dataType: "json",
            async:
        false,
            success:

        function(msg) {
            ////debugger;
            window.location.href = '/PhaseDocuments/UpdateModelView/60cfe283-dcd6-47db-9f85-3cf662cd5ccf' + '/' + model.PhaseDocumentId;
        }
        });
```

the model var is the Json version of my controller model

```
var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelNoHTML, Formatting.Indented,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    }));
```

SOLUTION
The solution is on a similar question

[SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051063/how-can-url-action-already-know-the-routevalues-without-me-setting-them?rq=1)

Comment: What does the client-side code look like after the page renders?  What is `model`?  Is that really client-side, or are you trying to use the server-side `model` object?  If the latter, why not use it in the call to `.Action()` directly?

Comment: Do you have a route defaulting the value of `id`?

Comment: No Patric but i found the solution

Comment: Then add it as an answer for future reference.

Comment: I can not add the answers because I'm a low profile

Comment: Don't be so negative about yourself ;). You can answer from 1 rep, so I think you could self-answer your question.